# php session id changing for no reason

Tags: php, session

I'm currently using Valum's File Uploader on Wamp and everything had been going smoothly until now. Inside the uploader's php file I made it save the uploaded file to the current user's folder by reading from the session data to get the current user. However, it is creating a new session everytime I call it for some unknown reason. I have checked the cookies and they return the correct session. I also checked the `session_id()` and it also returns the correct session. However, it always creates a new session for some reason. I even explicitly set the session id with the `session_id()` function. However, none of this works for some reason. It's returning the correct id but it doesn't save to the correct id. Anyone know why this is happening?

Below is the modified Uploader.php code.

```
<?php
//if (!empty($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])){
session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
//}
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
/**
 * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
 */


class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {    
        $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $temp = tmpfile();
        $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);

        if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
            return false;
        }

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        fclose($target);

        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
            return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];            
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
        }      
    }   
}

/**
 * Handle file uploads via regular form post (uses the $_FILES array)
 */
class qqUploadedFileForm {  
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {

        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function getName() {
        return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        return $_FILES['qqfile']['size'];
    }
}

class qqFileUploader {
    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $file;
    function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
        $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
        $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

        $this->checkServerSettings();       

        if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
        } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
        } else {
            $this->file = false; 
        }
    }

    private function checkServerSettings(){        
        $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

        if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
            $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
            die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size - Upload size: $uploadSize, postSize: $postSize, sizeLimit: $this->sizeLimit'}");    
        }        
    }

    private function toBytes($str){
        $val = trim($str);
        $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
        }
        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
     */
    function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
        if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
        }

        if (!$this->file){
            return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
        }

        $size = $this->file->getSize();

        if ($size == 0) {
            return array('error' => 'File is empty');
        }

        if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
            return array('error' => 'File is too large');
        }

        $pathinfo = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
        $filename = $pathinfo['filename'];
        //$filename = md5(uniqid());
        $ext = $pathinfo['extension'];

        if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
            $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
            return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
        }

        if(!$replaceOldFile){
            /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
            while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
                $filename .= rand(10, 99);
            }
        }

        if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
            return array('success'=>true,'file'=>$filename . '.' . $ext);
        } else {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
                'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
        }

    }    
}

// list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$allowedExtensions = array();
// max file size in bytes
$sizeLimit = 8 * 1024 * 1024;

$uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);
$result = $uploader->handleUpload("../users/".$_SESSION['id']."/uploads/");
// to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>session_id()));
    //echo '{"error":"You are not logged in. Please log in to upload files."}';
}
?>
```

**Update**
I now see something a bit unusual. It seems like it's copying the session and leaving behind the old session file - just like what `session_regnerate_id()` does. However, I don't have that anywhere in my code.

Comment: have you checked the session_start()

Comment: Yes, I have started the session. Otherwise it wouldn't have created another session in the first place.

Comment: I have now updated and included the code

Comment: can you please put session_start at the top and then do the session_id

Comment: have you checked that the session is being stored correctly to disk in the configured temp folder? Do sessions behave correctly outside of this script? Also try without session_id(), you shouldn't need that, you only need to set a session_name()

Comment: @scuzzy: don't need to set session name either, unless you're overriding whatever's set in php.ini. Typically you only need session_start() and nothing else.

Comment: @scuzzy I was viewing the temp folder while trying it out. The path is definitely correct, and the sessions work in other php files in the same folder...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case inserting this line...

```
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
```

...right before `session_start()` solved it.